# Box covers half of the screen on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hello Every one i need your help ! i am trying to create  create a javascript code that and here is the ideal if any one could contribute to it.

its like a social media, when users enter the site the `is_user_logged_is` parameter is loaded - its a function that checks if users is logged in, (don't bother about this).

i want to create a code that when non-registered users enters the site they could scrool down to view item in the page, however when user scroll to 700px a big white box from beneath comes covering one third of the whole screen and on scrolling to say 1400px. it covers half of the whole screen and on scrolling to 2000px it covers all the whole screen.

please ignore the user log in concept , i used that to make the illustration more suitable.

please how to i create this with javascipt ?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: please read post again, i made some corrections

Comment: You haven't asked a question merely a requirement!

Comment: i am so sorry but this is how best i can explain this, read the post again, i made yet another change.

Comment: If it's a website content protection, it's really useless... Unless you remove the data behind the white box, there is no need to be an engineer to do a right click, inspect element and press suppr key

Comment: @Fefux i know, but it i need this, do you have any way i can do this?

Comment: its useless but pinterest uses it.

Answer (score 1):

You can play with that a bit. And get familiar with jQuery.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 120) {
      $("#up").css("display", "block");
      $("#up").css("top", "300px");      
      $("#up").height($("#content").outerHeight(true));
    } else {
      $("#up").hide("fast");
      $("#up").height(0); 
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#up {
  width:100%;
  background:white;
  opacity: 0.9;
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  display:none;
  transition-duration: .5s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content">
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</p>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</p>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</p>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</p>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</p>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</p>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</p>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</p>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</p>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</p>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</p>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</p>
</div>
<div id="up"></div>
```

Comment: bro i am so new to javascript, i need a comprehensive explanation to this, thank you.

Comment: thank you bro, is there any way i make it so that when user already reached the white page the and they try to scroll up they would also meet the white page

Answer (score 1):

I'm hoping this is what you are looking for.

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var scrollPos = $(this).scrollTop(),
    winHeight;
  if (scrollPos >= 700 && scrollPos < 1400) {
    $(".popup").addClass("active");
  } else if (scrollPos >= 1400 && scrollPos < 2000) {
    $(".popup").addClass("active half");
  } else if (scrollPos >= 2000) {
    $(".popup").removeClass("half").addClass("active full");
  }
}).scroll();
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.container {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 2500px;
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.popup {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 10%;
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 33%;
  transition: max-height 0.5s ease;
}

.popup.half {
  max-height: 50%;
}

.popup.full {
  max-height: 100%;
}

.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="popup">

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks alot, thats excatly what i need.

Comment: is they any way i make it so that when the scroll reaches the white page and users try to scroll up to the top back the whole screen becomes blank

Comment: I think the code already does that

Comment: here is the concept, users enter the page at first the would make like 3 scrools based on the device width i set it to,  but when users tries to scrool back to the top, a white box appears covering the whole page, thanks for ur tym bro

Comment: Updated the code as per your requirement.